# At mobile device too late to use display none, block

Tags: javascript, css, performance, responsive-design

At Pc it works well.
but mobile it is too late. 
is any other faster method or the others?

```
function country_change(country,countries)
{   
    var cls = document.getElementsByClassName("country_events"); 

    if(document.readyState == "loading")
    { 
        alert('not loading.');
    } else 
    {   
        for (n=0; n < cls.length; n++) 
        {   

            var elem = cls[n];
            var div_elem = elem.getElementsByTagName('div').length;

            for (m=1; m < div_elem; m++) 
            {   
                if (elem.getAttribute('name') == country)
                {
                    if (elem.getElementsByTagName('div')[m].style.display == "none")
                    {
                        elem.getElementsByTagName('div')[m].style.display="block";
                        increaseHeight()
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                        elem.getElementsByTagName('div')[m].style.display="none";
                        increaseHeight()
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

at pc it works about 1~3 seconds, but mobile it takes almost 10~20 sec.
i think display is not good method, but there is no other way isn't it?

Comment: You can greatly optimise the loop by removing many of the calls to *getElementsByClassName*.

Comment: Because of use getElementByClassName it just 20~30 obj.

Comment: Sure, but you call it 3 times instead of once. It's an expensive method to call and work with as it's a live NodeList. Making *cls* static will help too. These are easy big gains in peformance. No promises that it will be super fast, but probably noticeably faster.

Answer (score 0):

The collection returned by:

```
var cls = document.getElementsByClassName("country_events");
```

is live, so any modification to the DOM may require the browser to refresh the collection. That may happen a lot more often that you think (and much more in some browsers than others), so you may want to convert that to an array or use *querySelectorAll* (which returns a static collection) instead:

```
var cls = document.querySelectorAll(".country_events");
```

Then you have:

```
        var elem = cls[n];
        var div_elem = elem.getElementsByTagName('div').length;
```

so it is good to cache *elem*, but *getElementsByTagName* also returns a live collection so use *querySelectorAll* again:

```
        var div_elem = elem.querySelectorAll('div').length;
```

*div_elem* seems an inappropriate name, perhaps *divCount* would be better?

Then:

```
            if (elem.getAttribute('name') == country)
```

you can save a method call by accessing the property directly:

```
            if (elem.name == country)
```

And then the awfully wastefull:

```
       if (elem.getElementsByTagName('div')[m].style.display == "none")
                {
                    elem.getElementsByTagName('div')[m].style.display="block";
                    increaseHeight()
```

You got the list of divs earlier, so cache it there

```
  var divs = elem.querySelectorAll('div');
  var divCount = divs.length;
```

Now reuse it:

```
       if (divs[m].style.display == 'none') {
         divs[m].style.display = '';
       } else {
         divs[m].style.display = 'none';
       }
       increaseHeight();
```

which can be shortened to:

```
       divs[m].style.display == divs[m].style.display == 'none'? '' : 'none';
       increaseHeight();
```

However the conditional operator is usually slower than the equivalent if..else.

So the function becomes:

```
function country_change(country,countries) {   
    var cls = document.querySelectorAll('.country_events'); 

    if(document.readyState == "loading") { 
        alert('not loading.');

    } else {   

        for (var n=0, nLen=cls.length; n<nLen; n++) {
            var elem = cls[n];
            var divs = elem.querySelectorAll('div');
            var divCount = divs.length;

            for (var m = 1; m < divCount; m++) {

                if (elem.name == country) {

                    if (divs[m].style.display == 'none') {
                        divs[m].style.display = '';

                    } else {
                      divs[m].style.display = 'none';
                    }

                    increaseHeight()
                }
             }
         }    
    }
}
```

Note that *querySelectorAll* is not supported by IE 7 and lower.

Setting *element.style.display* to '' (empty string) allows it to return to it's default or computed style and means you don't have to know what that is for each different type of element or what is included in CSS rules.

Comment: i followed you, but (divs = elem.querySelectorAll('div'); div_elem[m].style.display ) seems to can not modify display. it is anything happen.